# jquery+on iterating loop how can i know which element is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, user-interface

I am having a list which is nothing but country flag, country name and country code which actually i derived from JSON

and i had written for loop to render the html elements like this

```
data = 

  [
  {
        "name": "INDIA ",
        "code": "93",
        "url": 'https://www.countryflags.io/in/flat/64.png' 
    }, {
        "name": "JAPAN ",
        "code": "355",
        "url": 'https://www.countryflags.io/jp/flat/64.png'
    }]

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  
  var countryName = data[i].name;
  var countrtDialCode = data[i].code;
  var countryUrl = data[i].url;
  var badge = document.createElement('div');
  badge.className = 'badge';
  badge.innerHTML =
  '<div id="listSection">'+
    '<div style="display:flex">'+
    '<div id="flagSection">'+'<img style="height:10px;width:20px;margin-top:4px;" src='+countryUrl+'>'+'</div>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
    '<div id="nameSection">' + countryName + '</div>' +'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
    '<div id="codeSection">' + countrtDialCode + '</div>' 
     +'</div>'+
     '</div>'
    
  document.getElementById('countries-list').appendChild(badge);
}
```

also i have a divs section

```
<div id="inputSection"> </div>

<div id="countries-list">

</div>
```

and i have done like when you click on input section the list will come and i can choose from the list and i need **ONLY** the flag should be shown

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#countries-list').addClass('hideSection').removeClass('showSection')
    });
    $('#inputSection').click(function(){
        $('#countries-list').addClass('showSection').removeClass('hideSection')
    })


    </script>
```

so when i click india JSON from list , i should display indian flag in inputSection again if i click input section list should come and again if i choose NEPAL, indian flag should be replaced with NEPAL flag.

Have 2 problem.First one i am unable to write click function in INNERHTML to identify which country clicked and second how to retrieve the flag section and show it in inputSection.

Any fiddle will be highly helpful and thankful

Comment: You are repeating ids on elements.  That is invalid html from a web standards perspective.  You should use classes instead, if you want a repeating identifier

Comment: Please provide some sample data so it is easier to test the behavior.

Comment: Not relevant to the question: you should have a single `showSection` (or `hideSection`) with the other (hide/show) being the default - then you only need to toggle a single class

Comment: @hev1 added json dummy data

Comment: 2 problems mainly
- how to write onclick to innerHTML ? because i need to know which flag is clicked
- then replace the inputSection with flag and cycle repeats [again if user clicks another flag , already selected flag should be removed and new flag should be visible ]. I repeat only the flag should be visible

Comment: So does the user click the flag or the country name? If the flag, why would you need it in the input section, if the country name, then you know which country was clicked. .. Just needing some clarification. Knowing your goal would help put your problems in perspective.

Comment: @PeterKA we are not sure what element user might click , he might have clicked flag either or name or code. but we will displaying flag only in input section (we should know which element he clicked to show flag in inout section)

Comment: Basically am trying to achieve behaviour or select input without using it .. due to some other issues

Comment: @Taplar I will change accordingly .. HTML is kind of dummy ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is a clone of the flag section in the input section, then this is all you need:

```
$('.listSection').on('click', function() {
    $('#inputSection').html( $('.flagSection', this).clone() );
});
```

However, you have to convert every occurrence of `id` in the HTML in your JS to `class`, as in the working demo below. Id attribute values should be unique.

```js
$(function() {
    const data = [{
          "name": "INDIA ",
          "code": "93",
          "url": 'https://www.countryflags.io/in/flat/64.png' 
      }, {
          "name": "JAPAN ",
          "code": "355",
          "url": 'https://www.countryflags.io/jp/flat/64.png'
      }];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      var countryName = data[i].name;
      var countrtDialCode = data[i].code;
      var countryUrl = data[i].url;
      var badge = document.createElement('div');
      badge.className = 'badge';
      badge.innerHTML =
      '<div class="listSection">'+
        '<div style="display:flex">'+
        '<div class="flagSection">'+'<img style="height:10px;width:20px;margin-top:4px;" src='+countryUrl+'>'+'</div>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
        '<div class="nameSection">' + countryName + '</div>' +'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
        '<div class="codeSection">' + countrtDialCode + '</div>' 
         +'</div>'+
         '</div>'

      document.getElementById('countries-list').appendChild(badge);
    }
    
    $('.listSection').on('click', function() {
        console.log( {name: $('.nameSection',this).text(), code: $('.codeSection', this).text()} );
        $('#inputSection').html( $('.flagSection', this).clone() );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="inputSection"> </div>

<div id="countries-list">

</div>
```

**NOTE**

Since there's not mention in the documentation of `.html( jQueryObject )` even thought it works in the above demo, I'll provide an alternative that uses `.empty()` and `.append()` methods:

```
$('#inputSection').empty().append( $('.flagSection', this).clone() );
```

Comment: Not saying this is wrong, but doesn't `.clone` give you an object and `.html()` take text?  So would be `$("#dest").html($("#src").html())` ?  Snippet works so I guess jquery handles it.

Comment: @peterKA Thanks a lot. quick doubt on listSection click function, is there anyway to console the whole object i clicked (like INDIA,93)

Comment: Try `console.log( {name: $('.nameSection',this).text(), code: $('.codeSection', this).text()} );` or any such; see updated demo.

Comment: Good point @freedomn-m! I'll update my answer to give an alternative supported by the documentation.